# Access Detail Table datakeynames on rowdrop event telerik

Tags: c#-4.0, telerik, telerik-grid, radgrid

I am using telerik nested rad grid. Please take a look at code.

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="radGridRoutes" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowStatusBar="True"
        AllowSorting="True" AllowPaging="True" ClientSettings-Scrolling-EnableVirtualScrollPaging="false"
        ClientSettings-Scrolling-AllowScroll="false"
        OnNeedDataSource="Routes_NeedDataSource" OnDetailTableDataBind="radGridRoutes_DetailTableDataBind" AllowFilteringByColumn="True"
        EnableLinqExpressions="false" OnInsertCommand="Routes_InsertCommand"
        OnUpdateCommand="radGridRoutes_UpdateCommand"
        OnItemCommand="radGridRoutes_ItemCommand"
        OnPreRender="radGridRoutes_PreRender" ClientSettings-AllowRowsDragDrop="true"
        OnRowDrop="radGridRoutes_RowDrop">
        <ClientSettings AllowDragToGroup="True">
            <Selecting AllowRowSelect="True" />
        </ClientSettings>
        <GroupingSettings CaseSensitive="false" />
        <SelectedItemStyle CssClass="SelectedItem" />
        <PagerStyle Mode="NextPrevNumericAndAdvanced"></PagerStyle>
        <ValidationSettings CommandsToValidate="PerformInsert,Update" EnableModelValidation="true"
            EnableValidation="true" />
        <FilterItemStyle BackColor="#F8F8F8" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        <FilterMenu EnableImageSprites="false">
        </FilterMenu>
        <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="ID" AllowMultiColumnSorting="false"
            Width="100%" CommandItemDisplay="Top" Name="Routes">
            <AlternatingItemStyle BackColor="WhiteSmoke" />

            <DetailTables>
                <telerik:GridTableView OnRowDrop="radGridRoutes_RowDrop" ClientSettings-AllowRowsDragDrop="true" 
                    DataKeyNames="ID,DisplayOrder,RouteID" Width="100%" runat="server"
                    CommandItemDisplay="Top" Name="Stops" AllowFilteringByColumn="false">
                    <CommandItemSettings AddNewRecordText="Add New Stops" ShowAddNewRecordButton="true" />
                    <ParentTableRelation>
                        <%-- <telerik:GridRelationFields DetailKeyField="ID" MasterKeyField="ID" />--%>
                    </ParentTableRelation>
                    <RowIndicatorColumn Visible="True" FilterControlAltText="Filter RowIndicator column">
                    </RowIndicatorColumn>
                    <ExpandCollapseColumn Visible="True" FilterControlAltText="Filter ExpandColumn column">
                    </ExpandCollapseColumn>
                    <Columns>
                        <telerik:GridEditCommandColumn ButtonType="ImageButton" UniqueName="EditTask" EditText="Edit"
                            UpdateText="Update" CancelText="Cancel">
                            <HeaderStyle Width="20px" />
                        </telerik:GridEditCommandColumn>

                        <telerik:GridTemplateColumn SortExpression="Name" HeaderText="Name" UniqueName="Name"
                            HeaderButtonType="TextButton" HeaderStyle-Width="15%" ItemStyle-Width="15%" DataField="tName">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <%# Eval("Name")%>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Width="250px" Text='<%# Eval("Name")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="requiredName" ControlToValidate="txtName"
                                    CssClass="validationMessage" ErrorMessage="Name is required."
                                    Text="* required" runat="server" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                        </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                        <telerik:GridTemplateColumn SortExpression="Comment" HeaderText="Comment" UniqueName="Comment"
                            HeaderButtonType="TextButton" DataField="Comment">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <%# Eval("Comment")%>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtComment" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="4" Width="250px" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Comment")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                        </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

                        <telerik:GridTemplateColumn SortExpression="Address" HeaderText="Address"
                            DataField="Address" UniqueName="Address" HeaderButtonType="TextButton">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <%# Eval("Address")%>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddress" Width="250px" TextMode="MultiLine" Text='<%# Bind("Address") %>' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                            </EditItemTemplate>
                        </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

                        <telerik:GridTemplateColumn SortExpression="Phone" HeaderText="Phone" UniqueName="Phone"
                            HeaderButtonType="TextButton" DataField="Phone">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <%# Eval("Phone")%>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPhone" Rows="4" Width="250px" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Phone")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                        </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

                        <telerik:GridTemplateColumn SortExpression="Email" HeaderText="Email" UniqueName="Email"
                            HeaderButtonType="TextButton" DataField="Email">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <%# Eval("Email")%>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" Rows="4" Width="250px" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Email")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                        </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

                        <telerik:GridTemplateColumn SortExpression="ManagerName" HeaderText="ManagerName" UniqueName="ManagerName"
                            HeaderButtonType="TextButton" DataField="ManagerName">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <%# Eval("ManagerName")%>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtManagerName" Rows="4" Width="250px" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ManagerName")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                        </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

                        <telerik:GridTemplateColumn SortExpression="NumberOfRooms" HeaderText="#Rooms" UniqueName="NumberOfRooms"
                            HeaderButtonType="TextButton" DataField="NumberOfRooms">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <%# Eval("NumberOfRooms")%>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtNumberOfRooms" Width="250px" Rows="4" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("NumberOfRooms")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                        </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

                        <telerik:GridTemplateColumn SortExpression="Merchandising" HeaderText="Merchandising" UniqueName="Merchandising"
                            HeaderButtonType="TextButton" DataField="Merchandising">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <%# Eval("Merchandising")%>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtMerchandising" Width="250px" Rows="4" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Merchandising")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                        </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

                        <telerik:GridTemplateColumn SortExpression="Frequency" HeaderText="Frequency"
                            DataField="Frequency" UniqueName="Frequency" HeaderButtonType="TextButton">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <%# GetFrequencyName(Convert.ToInt32(Eval("FrequencyID"))) %>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="drpFreq" runat="server" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="ID"
                                    AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="--Select--" Value="-1">
                                    </asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                        </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

                        <telerik:GridTemplateColumn SortExpression="DisplayOrder" HeaderText="Display Order" UniqueName="DisplayOrder"
                            HeaderButtonType="TextButton" HeaderStyle-Width="15%" ItemStyle-Width="15%" DataField="DisplayOrder">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <%# Eval("DisplayOrder")%>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtDisplayOrder" runat="server" Width="250px" Text='<%# Eval("DisplayOrder")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="requiredDisplayOrder" ControlToValidate="txtDisplayOrder"
                                    CssClass="validationMessage" ErrorMessage="Display Order is required."
                                    Text="* required" runat="server" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                        </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

                        <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Delete" AllowFiltering="false">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDelete" CommandName="DeleteStops" CommandArgument=' <%# Eval("ID") %>' runat="server" OnClientClick="javascript:if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to delete Stop?')) {
                                         return false;
                                     }">Delete</asp:LinkButton>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

                    </Columns>
                    <EditFormSettings>
                        <EditColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter EditCommandColumn column">
                        </EditColumn>
                    </EditFormSettings>
                </telerik:GridTableView>
            </DetailTables>
            <RowIndicatorColumn Visible="True" FilterControlAltText="Filter RowIndicator column">
            </RowIndicatorColumn>
            <ExpandCollapseColumn Visible="True" FilterControlAltText="Filter ExpandColumn column">
            </ExpandCollapseColumn>
            <Columns>
                <telerik:GridEditCommandColumn ButtonType="ImageButton" CancelText="Cancel" EditText="Edit"
                    UpdateText="Update" UniqueName="EditRoutes" ItemStyle-Width="5%">
                    <HeaderStyle Width="5%" />
                </telerik:GridEditCommandColumn>
                <telerik:GridTemplateColumn SortExpression="Name" HeaderText="Name" UniqueName="RouteName"
                    HeaderButtonType="TextButton" HeaderStyle-Width="20%" ItemStyle-Width="20%" DataField="Name">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%# Eval("Name")%>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtRouteName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="requiredRouteName" ControlToValidate="txtRouteName"
                            CssClass="validationMessage" ErrorMessage="Name is required."
                            Text="* required" runat="server" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                <telerik:GridTemplateColumn SortExpression="Comment" HeaderText="Comment" UniqueName="Comment"
                    HeaderButtonType="TextButton" DataField="Comment">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%# Eval("Comment")%>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtComment" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="4" Width="250px" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Comment")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

                <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Delete" AllowFiltering="false">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDelete" CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument=' <%# Eval("ID") %>' runat="server" OnClientClick="javascript:if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to delete route?')) {
                                         return false;
                                     }">Delete</asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
            </Columns>
            <SortExpressions>
                <telerik:GridSortExpression FieldName="Name"></telerik:GridSortExpression>
            </SortExpressions>
            <CommandItemSettings AddNewRecordText="Add New Route" ShowAddNewRecordButton="true" />
            <EditFormSettings>
                <EditColumn UniqueName="EditCommandColumn1" FilterControlAltText="Filter EditCommandColumn1 column">
                </EditColumn>
            </EditFormSettings>
        </MasterTableView>
    </telerik:RadGrid>
```

And the code behind rowDrop event is

```
protected void radGridRoutes_RowDrop(object sender, GridDragDropEventArgs e)
    {
        GridDataItem RowDragged = e.DraggedItems.FirstOrDefault();
        e.DraggedItems[0].GetDataKeyValue("DisplayOrder");
        int OriginalID = Convert.ToInt32(RowDragged.GetDataKeyValue("ID"));
        int OriginalOrder = Convert.ToInt32(RowDragged.GetDataKeyValue("DisplayOrder"));
        int RouteID = Convert.ToInt32(RowDragged.GetDataKeyValue("RouteID"));

        int DestID = Convert.ToInt32(e.DestDataItem.GetDataKeyValue("ID"));
        int DestOrder = Convert.ToInt32(e.DestDataItem.GetDataKeyValue("DisplayOrder"));
        UpdateOrder(OriginalID, OriginalOrder, DestID, RouteID);
    }
```

Now the problem is i want to access the datakeyNames from the nested gridTableView. I am not able to figure that out. Please provide me suggestions how to get the ID,DisplayOrder,RouteID from nested gridtableview in rowdrop event. Currently it is giving null values to me.

Comment: If you dragged parent row then you will not get those keys. You will get those only when if you dragged child rows from the grid. Either you have to stop drag n drop in parent row or have to identify the row in the server side row drop event. Please provide your input.

Comment: @jayeshGoyani So you mean to say that i should make radGird's  ClientSettings-AllowRowsDragDrop="true" to false and then make it true for telerik:GridTableView ?
If i am doing that thing , i am not able to even drag the child grid's rows.

Comment: I will provide you code for those suggestion. We have to stop the drag n drop in parent row, Only I want to know that you want solution in clinet side or server side.

Comment: I want the server side solution for this as i am performing update operation to update the DisplayOrder in database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with the below code snippet.

**ASPX**

```
<telerik:GridTableView Name="Child" OnRowDrop="radGridRoutes_RowDrop" ClientSettings-AllowRowsDragDrop="true" DataKeyNames="ID,DisplayOrder,RouteID" Width="100%" runat="server" CommandItemDisplay="Top" Name="Stops" AllowFilteringByColumn="false">
```

**ASPX.CS**

```
protected void radGridRoutes_RowDrop(object sender, GridDragDropEventArgs e)
{
        GridDataItem RowDragged = e.DraggedItems.FirstOrDefault();

    if (RowDragged.OwnerTableView.Name == "Child")
    {
        // Row Dragged from child Grid

            e.DraggedItems[0].GetDataKeyValue("DisplayOrder");
            int OriginalID = Convert.ToInt32(RowDragged.GetDataKeyValue("ID"));
            int OriginalOrder = Convert.ToInt32(RowDragged.GetDataKeyValue("DisplayOrder"));
            int RouteID = Convert.ToInt32(RowDragged.GetDataKeyValue("RouteID"));

             // You can also check same thing for Drop Item
            int DestID = Convert.ToInt32(e.DestDataItem.GetDataKeyValue("ID"));                 int DestOrder = Convert.ToInt32(e.DestDataItem.GetDataKeyValue("DisplayOrder"));
            UpdateOrder(OriginalID, OriginalOrder, DestID, RouteID);
    }
}
```

Update 1:

If above code is not working then please try with the below code snippet.

Method 1:

**ASPX**

```
<telerik:GridTableView Name="Child" ClientDataKeyNames="ID,DisplayOrder,RouteID" OnRowDrop="radGridRoutes_RowDrop" ClientSettings-AllowRowsDragDrop="true"  DataKeyNames="ID,DisplayOrder,RouteID" Width="100%" runat="server" CommandItemDisplay="Top" Name="Stops" AllowFilteringByColumn="false">
......
......
<ClientSettings>
    <ClientEvents OnRowDragStarted="RowDragStarted" />
</ClientSettings>
```

**JS Code**

```
    function RowDragStarted(sender, eventArgs) {
        var tblvew = eventArgs.get_tableView().get_name();
        if(tblvew == null || tblvew == undefined || tblvew != 'Child')
        {
            eventArgs.set_cancel(true);
        }
    }
OR

function RowDragStarted(sender, eventArgs) {
    var route = eventArgs.getDataKeyValue("RouteID");
    if(route == null || route  == '')
    {
        eventArgs.set_cancel(true);
    }
}
```

Let me know if any concern.

Comment: Hi, I made the changes but it doesn't make any difference. I am able to get only the RowDragged.GetDataKeyValue("ID") as before but DisplayOrder and RouteID are still null. Is there any mistake in formation of nested grid ?? Please help me out with this.

Comment: Have you added 'Name="Child"' in GridTableView?

Comment: I also added client side solution in above code snippet.

Comment: Hi thanks. I found the problem within my implementation only. But thanks for your help. I really appreciate your concerns.

Comment: i just have a quick question. how can i bind the nested grid again in the rowDrop event ??

Comment: 'e.DestDataItem.OwnerTableView.Rebind();' Please try with this code. Let me know if any concern.